# Can this exponential function be represented in terms of the Meijer-G or Fox-H functions?

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms

For those who are experts with special functions, I was wondering if the exponential function given below can be represented in terms of the Meijer-G, Fox-H or any other special function.

$\gamma$ is a real number greater than or equal to zero, and k is positive real number.

$$\exp\left({-\ln^2 (\gamma^k)} \right)$$

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious- why would you want a special function here, when you already have an explicit expression in elementary functions? It doesn't get much simpler than this. Though I think it would look better like this: $$\exp \left(-k^2 \ln^2 \gamma \right)$$